# Why aren't all surjective continuous homomorphisms of topological groups open?

Tags: topological-groups, quotient-spaces, quotient-group, open-map, continuous-homomorphisms

My apologies if this a naive question.

Let $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ be a continuous surjective homomorphism of topological groups. Denote the kernel of $\phi$ by $N$, then:
$$\begin{align}
f:G\times N&\longrightarrow G\\
(g,n)&\longmapsto g\cdot n
\end{align}$$
is a continuous map. Indeed let $U\subset G$ be an open set, then if $\mu:G\times G$ denotes the multiplication map, we have that:
$$f^{-1}(U)=\mu^{-1}(U)\cap (G\times N)$$
Since $\mu^{-1}(U)$ is open in $G\times N$, it follows that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $G\times N$, when equipped with subspace topology. Therefore $N$ acts continuously on $G$ from the right. We can take the topological quotient, given by the equivalence relation:
$$g\sim h\Leftrightarrow \exists n\in N, g=h\cdot n$$
this is the same equivalence relationship defining $G/N$, and an isomorphism theorem guarantees that $G/N\cong H$, as groups.

We have by assumption that $\phi$ is continuous, and also satisfies all the properties of an algebraic quotient map. However, one can show that the topological quotient map $\pi:G\rightarrow G/N$ is always open even in the case where $G$ is just an arbitrary topological space and $N$ acts on it continuously from the right. So, what is stopping $\phi$ from being the topological group? I know that there is an open mapping theorem for topological groups which places considerable restrictions on the possible groups, so something is wrong with just saying $\phi$ is also the topological projection map, but I don't see why that is...

Comment: Consider the identity map from $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology to $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology.

Comment: @user43208 Are you saying that the topologies on $H$ and topological quotient $G/N$ might not coincide?

Comment: @Chris If $\hat{\phi}:G/N\to H$ is the induced group isomorphism then $\hat{\phi}\circ\pi=\phi$. True, $\pi$ is indeed an open map. However, $\hat{\phi}$ might not be open. The analogue of the isomorphism theorems doesn't work in the best possible way for topological groups. This map is necessary continuous, but might not be a homeomorphism. So we can't conclude that $\phi$ is open.

Comment: @Mark Thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: Mark already answered the question, but in the example I gave, $G/N = \mathbb{R}/1$ again has the discrete topology. I really was positing the example as a quick answer to the title question, and as an example to test your argument on.

Comment: @user43208 yes thank you, Marks answer made me see how your example applies.